# Event listener with anonymous function (typeError , toggle undefined)

Tags: javascript, events, dom, anonymous-function

I am new to **Javascript**.

I have two identical tables laid side by side. I would like to have a mirror effect. `case 1` works fine with no anonymous function.

However, there seems to be some problem in my `case 2` Javascript code which is vital for my project

**CASE 1**

```
 var table1td = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td");
 var table2td = document.querySelectorAll("#table2 td");

 for(var i=0; i<table2td.length; i++)
 {
    table2td[i].addEventListener("click",_click);
 }

 function _click() {
    this.classList.toggle("_changecolor");
 }
```

**CASE 2**

```
 var table1td = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td");
 var table2td = document.querySelectorAll("#table2 td");    

 for(var i=0; i<table2td.length; i++)
 {
    table2td[i].addEventListener("click", function(){_click(i)});
 }

function _click(index) {
    this.classList.toggle("_changecolor");
    table2td[9-index].classList.toggle("_changecolor");
}
```

(no changes in HTML,CSS code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You can't use `this` inside `_click` because it won't be your element. The element that fired the event will be bound to the anonymous function passed to `addEventListener`, not to `_click` (which, depeneding on the rest of your code, will either be bound to `undefined` or the global object `window`).

You can fix that by explicitly setting the `this` value when you call `_click` from within the anonymous function using `Function#call` or `Function#apply`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < table2td.length; i++) {
    table2td[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        _click.call(this);                       // passing the current this (of the anonymous function) to _click as we invoke it
    });
}

function _click() {
    this.classList.toggle("_changecolor");       // using this is OK
}
```

2. You can't use the indexes due to this [**famous problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

A quick fix will be to use `let` (which respects the block scope) instead of `var` (which doesn't):

```
for(let i = 0; i < table2td.length; i++) {       // using let instead of var
    table2td[i].addEventListener("click", function() { _click(i); });
}

function _click(index) {                         // using index is also OK
    table2td[index].classList.toggle("_changecolor");
}
```

Comment: understood problem 1 that is, how `this` keyword refers to anonymous function. but can you please tell me, how to pass variable `i` to the `_click` function (taking a parameter).

Comment: @Binary_10 It's already included in the answer (see **2.**). For more about that problem see the [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) (which is also included in the answer).